# Strange behavior or RAND in MariaDB: Single RAND delivers more than 1 result

Tags: mysql, random

When running the following query:

```
SELECT productid 
FROM product 
WHERE productid=ROUND(RAND()*(SELECT MAX(productid) FROM product));
```

The result should be 0 or 1 results (0 due to data gaps, 1 if a record is found), however it results in multiple results a good number of times (very easy to reproduce, 90% of queries have more than 1 result).

Sample output:

```
+-----------+
| productid |
+-----------+
|     11701 |
|     20602 |
|     22029 |
|     24994 |
+-----------+
```

(Number of records in DB is about 30k).

Running a single `SELECT RAND()` always results in a single result.

Explain:

```
explain SELECT productid  FROM product  WHERE productid=ROUND(RAND()*(SELECT MAX(productid) FROM product));
+----+-------------+---------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+-------+----------+------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref  | rows  | filtered | Extra                        |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+-------+----------+------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | product | NULL       | index | NULL          | idx_prod_url | 2003    | NULL | 31197 |    10.00 | Using where; Using index     |
|  2 | SUBQUERY    | NULL    | NULL       | NULL  | NULL          | NULL         | NULL    | NULL |  NULL |     NULL | Select tables optimized away |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+-------+----------+------------------------------+
```

Who can explain this behavior?

**Follow up**:
Following Martin's remark a rewrite of the query in:

```
SELECT productid FROM product 
WHERE productid=(SELECT ROUND(RAND()*(SELECT MAX(productid) FROM product)));
```

Explain:

```
explain SELECT productid FROM product WHERE productid=(SELECT ROUND(RAND()*(SELECT MAX(productid) FROM product)));
+----+----------------------+---------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+-------+----------+------------------------------+
| id | select_type          | table   | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref  | rows  | filtered | Extra                        |
+----+----------------------+---------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+-------+----------+------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY              | product | NULL       | index | NULL          | idx_prod_url | 2003    | NULL | 31197 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index     |
|  2 | UNCACHEABLE SUBQUERY | NULL    | NULL       | NULL  | NULL          | NULL         | NULL    | NULL |  NULL |     NULL | No tables used               |
|  3 | SUBQUERY             | NULL    | NULL       | NULL  | NULL          | NULL         | NULL    | NULL |  NULL |     NULL | Select tables optimized away |
+----+----------------------+---------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+-------+----------+------------------------------+
```

However despite the changed plan, the behavior stays the same.

**Follow up 2**:

Using an `INNER JOIN`, the behavior disappears:

```
SELECT a.productid  FROM product a 
INNER JOIN (SELECT ROUND(RAND()*(SELECT MAX(productid))) as productid 
   FROM product) b ON a.productid=b.productid;
```

Explain:

```
explain SELECT a.productid  FROM product a INNER JOIN (SELECT ROUND(RAND()*(SELECT MAX(productid))) as productid FROM product) b ON a.productid=b.productid;
+----+--------------------+------------+------------+--------+---------------+--------------+---------+-------+-------+----------+----------------+
| id | select_type        | table      | partitions | type   | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref   | rows  | filtered | Extra          |
+----+--------------------+------------+------------+--------+---------------+--------------+---------+-------+-------+----------+----------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | <derived2> | NULL       | system | NULL          | NULL         | NULL    | NULL  |     1 |   100.00 | NULL           |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | a          | NULL       | const  | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY      | 4       | const |     1 |   100.00 | Using index    |
|  2 | DERIVED            | product    | NULL       | index  | NULL          | idx_prod_url | 2003    | NULL  | 31197 |   100.00 | Using index    |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | NULL       | NULL       | NULL   | NULL          | NULL         | NULL    | NULL  |  NULL |     NULL | No tables used |
+----+--------------------+------------+------------+--------+---------------+--------------+---------+-------+-------+----------+----------------+
```

Comment: [In a WHERE clause, RAND() is evaluated each time the WHERE is executed.](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/rand/). See the recommended pattern here https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/data-sampling-techniques-for-efficiently-finding-a-random-row/

Comment: @MartinSmith Ok, following your reasoning and reading the query, I did a rewrite in which I encapsulated the RAND in the SELECT. The result stays the same though: Multiple executions still occur, while if this would be ran without the RAND, neither of the versions show this duplication behavior.

Comment: Your rewrite still isn't using the pattern in the docs. Do you get the same results with JOIN?

Comment: Just wrote a query using an INNER JOIN, that removes the issue. I do however seriously not see where the multiple executions would occur: Every RAND is ran against a single value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT productid 
FROM product 
ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1;
```

See [MySQL Select Random Records](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/select-random-records-database-table.aspx) for other random select options.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation:

When the query in the original post executes, Maria says, "I need to look at data from the table, product, so let me start with the first row."  Then, "Let me check the WHERE clause to see if I should use this row."  At that point, Maria calculates a random number and multiplies it by the largest productid, rounding it to an integer.  She checks to see if that integer equals the productid from the first row.  If it does not, then she forgets about that row.  If it does, then she selects the productid from that row and holds onto it.  Either way, she then moves on to the second row.  She calculates a (new) random number, multiplies it by the largest productid, and checks whether it equals the productid from the second row.  If it does not, she moves on.  If it does, she adds that productid to her list of selected values.  She does the same thing on the third row, etc.  The final output is then a list of zero to MAX(productid) productid values, each one independently selected with a probability of 1/MAX(productid).

When the query from Follow up 2 executes, the left side of the join is just a table.  For the right side of the join, Maria says, "I need to look at data from the table, product.  Since there is no WHERE clause, I will look at the whole table.  Oh my, I have an aggregate function, MAX(productid), in the SELECT clause.  That gives me a single value from the whole table."  She calculates a single random number and multiplies it by that value, creating a table, b, consisting of a single column, productid, with one row.  That table is then inner joined with the table, product, to find every row with a matching productid, which would be exactly one row, and the productid from that row is selected.

Note that if all you are looking for is the productid and you do not need any other data from the selected row, then the right side of the join is all you should need.

`SELECT ROUND(RAND()*(SELECT MAX(productid))) as productid from product;`

Note also that ROUND is probably not the right function for what you are trying to do.  This might be what you really want:

`SELECT FLOOR(1+RAND()*(SELECT MAX(productid))) as productid from product;`